# Java - I have a HashSet of Strings, and I want to somehow sort these strings by their length

Tags: java, string, data-structures, hashset

I really just need some way to find all the strings in the hashSet with the greatest length (whether it be one string or multiple). I figured I should sort the set on string length somehow first and then maybe iterate through it (going from longest strings to shortest so I can stop iteration after I've seen all the strings of greatest length). Can anyone help me figure out how best to go about this (mainly just concerned with finding out how to sort them by length efficiently)? Thanks.

Comment: You describe an `O(n log n)` algorithm for an operation whose naive implementation is `O(n)`: just iterate once keeping track of the longest string length and then again to get all strings of that length (the two could be combined, but that probably wouldn't be faster).

Comment: @perelman: wow, so simple yet so smart. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency gained by storing the strings in a `HashSet` for fast lookups will not help you when trying to find the longest string.  You'll need to update your data structure for that.

One option would be to store two separate data structures - a `TreeSet<Set<String>>` of sets of strings, where the comparator for the `TreeSet` just compares the length of the strings, plus the earlier `HashSet`.  You could insert a string into this hybrid data structure efficiently by just updating the appropriate set in the `TreeSet` to contain the new string and inserting the string into the `HashSet` like before.  It would also let you efficiently find all the largest strings simply by querying the `TreeSet` for its largest element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about maybe using a treeSet. Although this would definitely work in some situations, in mine I will already have the hash containing all the strings it ever will (no more will ever be added by the time I get it). So in this particular instance, it would make more sense for me to do what perelman suggested under my main post. Thanks anyway though.